# Static Padding Between CSS Flex Items

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexible layout in CSS that will wrap according to the client's resolution.

For example, on an ipad in landscape (1024px wide), i would like to display the following:

[image]

But on a playbook in portrait (600px wide), i would like to display the following:

[image]

I have *almost* everything working except the 20px margins. I cannot seem to figure out how to specify the margins for wrapped elements.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="box-row-fluid">
     <div class="col">Box 1</div>
     <div class="col">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-row-fluid {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box-row-fluid > .col {
    -webkit-flex: 1 400px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Code assumes that the browser is a valid webkit browser.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is a "valid webkit browser"?

Comment: I call an up-to-date webkit browser where flexboxes are supported in full a "valid webkit browser."

Comment: have you looked at justify-content in flexbox? i think that is the property you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do it like this [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrTfs/) (Edited `background color` for margin visibility)

CSS

```
.col:nth-child(1) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

For adding a margin between 2 `div` horizontally you can use [**@media query**](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/) for particular resolutions and add `margin-right: 20px;` for the other one

Explanation: Use `:nth-child(1)` because you are using `class="col"` for both `<div>`

Comment: This only works for the scenario where the boxes are wrapped. When this code appears on a wide screen where the boxes appear next to each other, the box 2 appears taller than box 1.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you include twitter bootstrap?

It would work with this to work then.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        Content box 1
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        Content box 1
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing you need to include is the "grid-system" very small and works great!

Comment: He's already got flexbox working and doesn't require the extra overhead.